# Quartz CronScheduleBuilder.atHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek don't working

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I needing to use Quartz to execute a job. and when I try create a trigger on this mode :

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(identityTRIGGER, "grupo 01")                 .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.atHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(11, 20, DateBuilder.THURSDAY)).build();
```

don´t fired at 11:20 on thursday.

I´ve tried to do (with cron expression):

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(identityTRIGGER, "grupo 01").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 20 11 * * 5 *") ).build();
```

and don't work eigther- shows the following message:

```
 Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented
```

**OBS: If I use another chron expression (like  "0/10 * * * * ?") this work **

what´s wrong with my trigger ?

tnx advanced

Comment: any updates? did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent exception "ParseException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented" do not use the `*` (all) value for day-of-month, but you could use `?` (any) instead.

This is the strange implementation limitation of quartz.

So, you could use expression

```
0 20 11 ? * 5 *
```